# Android BLE Fatal Exception: Main

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, fatal-error, bluegiga

I am trying to program an Android application that utilizes the BLE feature. I am able to scan and find the devices I am looking for but, when I try to connect to one of the devices, I receive the following error:

```
02-22 18:28:54.603: I/ViewRootImpl(4155): ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down
02-22 18:28:54.663: D/AndroidRuntime(4155): Shutting down VM
02-22 18:28:54.663: W/dalvikvm(4155): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41726e48)
02-22 18:28:54.663: I/ViewRootImpl(4155): ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155): Process: com.example.ble_test, PID: 4155
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.example.ble_test.DeviceControlActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DeviceControlActivity.java:217)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2644)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1096)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:744)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:883)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:118)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18471)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
02-22 18:28:54.663: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 18:33:54.696: I/Process(4155): Sending signal. PID: 4155 SIG: 9
02-22 18:33:55.326: D/ActivityThread(4235): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
```

Once I click on connect, the app shuts down because of the error. Here is my code for the DeviceControlActivity:

```
package com.example.ble_test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * For a given BLE device, this Activity provides the user interface to connect, display data,
 * and display GATT services and characteristics supported by the device.  The Activity
 * communicates with {@code BluetoothLeService}, which in turn interacts with the
 * Bluetooth LE API.
 */
public class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String TAG = DeviceControlActivity.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME = "DEVICE_NAME";
public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "DEVICE_ADDRESS";

private TextView mConnectionState;
private TextView mDataField;
private String mDeviceName;
private String mDeviceAddress;
private ExpandableListView mGattServicesList;
private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>> mGattCharacteristics =
        new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();
private boolean mConnected = false;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mNotifyCharacteristic;

private final String LIST_NAME = "NAME";
private final String LIST_UUID = "UUID";

// Code to manage Service lifecycle.
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};

// Handles various events fired by the Service.
// ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED: connected to a GATT server.
// ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED: disconnected from a GATT server.
// ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED: discovered GATT services.
// ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE: received data from the device.  This can be a result of read
//                        or notification operations.
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = true;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = false;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            clearUI();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
            displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
        }
    }
};

// If a given GATT characteristic is selected, check for supported features.  This sample
// demonstrates 'Read' and 'Notify' features.  See
// http://d.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html for the complete
// list of supported characteristic features.
private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
        new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                        int childPosition, long id) {
                if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                            mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                    final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                        // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                        // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                        if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                    mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                            mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                        }
                        mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                    }
                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                characteristic, true);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
};

private void clearUI() {
    mGattServicesList.setAdapter((SimpleExpandableListAdapter) null);
    mDataField.setText(R.string.no_data);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
    mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

    // Sets up UI references.
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_address)).setText(mDeviceAddress);
    mGattServicesList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.gatt_services_list);
    mGattServicesList.setOnChildClickListener(servicesListClickListner);
    mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_state);
    mDataField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_value);

    getActionBar().setTitle(mDeviceName);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    mBluetoothLeService = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);
    if (mConnected) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_connect:
            mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_disconnect:
            mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mConnectionState.setText(resourceId);
        }
    });
}

private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) {
        mDataField.setText(data);
    }
}

// Demonstrates how to iterate through the supported GATT Services/Characteristics.
// In this sample, we populate the data structure that is bound to the ExpandableListView
// on the UI.
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    if (gattServices == null) return;
    String uuid = null;
    String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
    String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
            = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
        currentServiceData.put(
                LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
        currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
        gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =
                new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                gattService.getCharacteristics();
        ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas =
                new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

        // Loops through available Characteristics.
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
            charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
            HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
            currentCharaData.put(
                    LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
            currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
            gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
        }
        mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
        gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
    }

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter gattServiceAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            gattServiceData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            gattCharacteristicData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
    );
    mGattServicesList.setAdapter(gattServiceAdapter);
}

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}
```

}

Here is also the menu file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
          android:title="@string/menu_refresh"
          android:checkable="false"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_connect"
          android:title="@string/menu_connect"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_disconnect"
          android:title="@string/menu_disconnect"
          android:orderInCategory="101"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

I was able to get beyond this point before but I'm not sure what the issue is this time. It must be something I overlooked. The device I'm trying to connect to is a Bluegiga BLE113 breakout board. Any help that you could offer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you got null pointer exception. And i think your mBluetoothLeService is never been set

Comment: the exception tells that it is a null pointer on line 217, inside method onOptionsItemSelected... onOptionsItemSelected(DeviceControlActivity.java:217)

Comment: Thank you for such quick replies. I saw that there was a null point exception coming from onOptionsItemSelected, but I'm not too sure what that means. Like, when I try connecting to the device, it returns a null?

Comment: So the error was coming from my Manifest file. When I tried connecting, it was trying to go to the BluetoothLeService but it couldn't because it was being referenced in a different project. Once I made the change, there was no more issues. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution to the error I was having. Previously, the BluetoothLeService reference in the Manifest file was:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.ble.BluetoothLeService"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

But that was references in a different project. Once I changed it to:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.ble_test2.BluetoothLeService"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

The problem was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I see from previous comments that you already know it's a null pointer exception.  The short answer is to check that mConnectionState isn't null before you call the setText() method on it.  Like so:

```
    public void run() {
        if (mConnectionState != null) {
            mConnectionState.setText(resourceId);
        }
    }
```

I think what's happening is that because the `BroadcastReceiver` fires asynchronously, it is firing somewhere between where you call `super.onCreate()` on line 141 and your where you set `mConnection()` to an actual `TextView` on line 152.